# Why doesn't java OptionalInt have an or() method like Optional<T> does?

Tags: java, option-type

With `Optional<T>` there is an `or()` method such that you can chain together Options among other things

```java
var o1  = Optional.<String>empty();

var o2 = Optional.of("some string");

Optional<String> o3 = o1.or(() -> o2); // o3 = o2
```

`OptionalInt` does not have this function.   How would you do something similar as above?

without resorting to

```java
        var oi1 = OptionalInt.empty();
        var oi2 = OptionalInt.empty();

        OptionalInt oi3 = oi1.isPresent() ? oi1 : oi2;
```

Comment: `Optional` doesn't even have an `#or` (edit: before Java 9), but both classes have `#orElse`, or more along the lines of your usage, `#orElseGet`: `o1.orElseGet(() -> o2);`. That said, not a lot of advantage in a supplier for a literal reference.

Comment: @Rogue Indeed [`or()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#or(java.util.function.Supplier)) was added in Java 9.

Comment: My mistake, it was added in Java 9 (not 11). That said, the usage can still be simulated via `#orElse` or `#orElseGet`, you simply need a `#map` call beforehand into an `Optional<Optional<T>>`. Overall, what's the use-case that this is actually intended for? Typically it'd be easier to simply "act upon" the optional and use some form of branching.

Comment: @Rogue `orElseGet()` doesn't return an option and it requires an int supplier not an option supplier, so that code doesn't work.

Comment: `o1.mapToObj(Optional::of).orElseGet(() -> /* retrieve other optional */)`. Again not the prettiest solution, but it's possible. What's the actual use-case here?

Comment: (Opinion) Another proof that this Java API is really poor. Might be better to use functional libraries if you have extensive usage of these structures.

Comment: OptionalInt doesn't have `map()` either.

Comment: @marathon `#mapToObj`, since you're going from `int` -> `Object`. My mistake.

Comment: @GaëlJ - agreed - Rust's version of this is very tidy.  But rust also allows primitives as generics arguments.

Comment: Why not just use `Optional<Integer>` if you really need to represent a _nullable Integer_?

Comment: @marathon you can simplify your double ternary expression with only `o1.isPresent() ? o1 : o2` but still it's ugly to have to do this.

Comment: @Rogue `map` or `mapToObj`, it doesn’t matter. `OptionalInt` has neither. It’s a general issue that the primitive optionals lack methods of `Optional`, `map`, `flatMap`, `filter` since day one. The new `or` method is not special…

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, the `OptionalInt` type does not allow to do this in any other way than what you suggest yourself:

```java
public OptionalInt orElse(OptionalInt o1, OptionalInt o2) {
  return o1.isPresent() ? o1 : o2;
}
```

*Could be changed to work with `Supplier` if needed*

Your best call would be to use `Optional<Integer>` in the first place.

As for the *why*, it's almost impossible to answer.